# What ISO standard for language codes does react-i18next / i18n follow?

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, iso, i18next, react-i18next

What ISO standard for language codes does react-i18next / i18n follow?

I've been searching around and my best guess is ISO 3166-1, but I can't find any concrete documentation.

Can anyone answer this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a standard for language codes in react-i18next. I have seen people using `'arab'` or `'dev'` ([like in this documentation](https://www.i18next.com/overview/api#languages)) as language codes. But yeah, there is probably no official documentation about this.

Answer (score 0):

Best seems to be if using the iana language tags format:

- en
- en-US
- en-GB

https://www.i18next.com/how-to/faq#how-should-the-language-codes-be-formatted